# Apache AWS lightsail python configuration ModuleNotFound error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I want to configure my python project to make use of apache,

All the configuration settings I have done to have my project to run apache as its server did not work but it was producing
`ModuleNotFound` error, but when I checked using `pip list` I saw that the package was installed. However when I run `python manage.py runserver ipaddress:8000`
it worked perfectly without any error. This show that there is configuration which was not working.

However all tutorials I have studied used apache2 directory as the location where their configuration takes place.

But when I checked apache2 directory I discovered that it was pointing to apache directory and if I tried to enter
into apache2 directory it would redirect me to apache directory so all my work is taking place in apache directory and not apache2 directory.

[image]

How can I get my project to make use of apache server and probably access apache2 as it is done in all the tutorials.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, the apache2 folder is just a symlink so do not worry if you edited the files under apache2 or apache, they are the same files. Regarding the Python's project you are trying to deploy, we have guides in our documentation that explains how to [create](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/django/get-started/start-django-project/) and [deploy](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/) projects on top of our solutions, did you take a look at them?

Comment: @JotaMartos thank you very much. Please can u help me I have a question similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072114/content-security-policy-csp-not-set-django-and-apache-server which does not have an answer. Please what could be  the reason why the static files are not loading